# Octave rlocus: format ploles and zero

Tags: control

I would like to make a rlocus plot with `Octave`. The problem is that the `poles` and `zeros` in the plot appear very small and rather hard to see by the naked eye. Is there a way to make these more visible? Specifying the size of `Markers` doesn't help. My MWE code is:

```
pkg load control
num=[0 0 0 1 3];
den=[1 5 20 16 0];
sys=tf(num,den)
pole(sys)'

rlocus(sys);

v=[-6 6 -6 6]; axis(v);axis('square');grid on;
```

The poles are at these locations:

```
-2.00000 - 3.46410i
-2.00000 + 3.46410i
-1.00000 - 0.00000i
 0.00000 - 0.00000i
```

And there is a zero at -3.0000. The plot from `Octave` is:

[image]

`Octave` adds a legend and shows a red dot for poles and a blue dot for zeros. These markers are so tiny that I have to zoom in at several magnitudes in order to see them. **In the figure attached one will not be able to see these small markers at all.**

Comment: How about adding a picture showing the too-small-to-properly-see artefacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the rlocus.m file, in \share\octave\packages\control-3.1.0\rlocus.m

Change lines 291 to 294 from:

```
set (hplt(kk--), "markersize", 2);
if (! isempty (rlzer))
  set (hplt(kk--), "markersize", 2);
endif
```

to:

```
set (hplt(kk--), "markersize", 10);
if (! isempty (rlzer))
  set (hplt(kk--), "markersize", 10);
endif
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @VincenteCunha Excellent! Are there any good tutorials on Octave for the control package? The web shows little resources.

Comment: Sorry, I could not say. I'm more of a matlab guy, never really used octave.

Comment: A few Matlab functions sadly do not have their equivalence in Octave and as far as I can see there is no proper resources of documents showing Octave being applied to control problems.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about *octave* but perhaps this  solution I just found will work.

Function File: axis ([x_lo x_hi y_lo y {_hi z_lo z_hi}])
(z is optional)

https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.1/Axis-Configuration.html

Comment: My question is more for the locations of poles and zeros that Octave draws very small on the plot. Thanks anyway.