# Octave pzmap: format poles and zeros

Tags: control, signal-processing, plot

This question is linked to this one:

[Octave rlocus: format ploles and zero](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/372728/octave-rlocus-format-ploles-and-zero)

I am using the **Octave** command `pzmap` but the size of the markers of the poles and zeros by default are very hard to see on the computer screen. I have looked at the `pzmap.m` file and changed the line:

```
h = plot (pol_args{:}, zer_args{:});
```

to

```
h = plot (pol_args{:}, zer_args{:},"markersize", 20);
```

but *there is no effect*.

and putting the `markersize` parameter in an actual code is not valid:

```
num=[1 3];
den=[1 5 20 16 0];
sys=tf(num,den);
pzmap(sys,"markersize", 20) %not valid
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you edited in pzmap.m is almost correct. You need to provide a "markersize" option for both poles and zeros.

Original plot:

[image]

After changing line 116 of \share\octave\packages\control-3.1.0\pzmap.m

```
h = plot (pol_args{:}, "markersize", 10, zer_args{:}, "markersize", 10);
```

[image]

Edit: to modify linewidth:

```
h = plot (pol_args{:}, "markersize", 10, "linewidth", 5, zer_args{:}, "markersize", 10, "linewidth", 5);
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Is there a way to make the markers appear bold i.e. by changing the line weight?

Comment: @user11206 Appended it to answer. Check the edit.

Comment: Great! It works fine in Octave.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code,

```
num=[1 3];
den=[1 5 20 16 0];
sys=tf(num,den);
pzmap(sys) h=pzmap(sys)

hh = findobj(gca,'type','line');
for jj=2:length(hh)
set(hh(jj),'MarkerSize',12,'MarkerEdgeColor','red','LineWidth',5);
end
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40001798/pzmap-or-pzplot-color-handle-for-multiple-plots)

And the result is,

[image]

Comment: Great. Is it possible to make the markers more pronounced as in "bold".

Comment: With the command: _set(h.allaxes.Children(1).Children, 'MarkerSize', 20)_, I am getting the error message: error: matrix cannot be indexed with .

Comment: @user11206 check the edited answer

Comment: pzplot is not yet part of Octave. Are you testing the code in Matlab or Octave?

Comment: @user11206 modified!. Check if this code works with Octave.

Comment: Unfortunately no. No effect on marker size even if I modify the value to 20 and no change in colour of the markers as well.

Comment: @user11206 Suggestion: post the question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Done. Thank you for the suggestion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50285757/octave-pzmap-format-poles-and-zeros